# Reshape in emgu cv

Tags: c#

I'm trying to reshape a matrix into a vector in Emgu CV in C#. The Reshape function of Emgu works completely correct when it is called for the first time in the code...but after that, it seems like it does nothing! Do you have any idea why is that?
here is the code:

**First usage**

```
myImg = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(a);
myImg2 = myImg.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

Matrix<float> tmp = new Matrix<float>(myImg2.Height, myImg2.Width);
CvInvoke.cvConvert(myImg2, tmp);
tmp = tmp.Transpose();
Matrix<float> reshaped_vect = new Matrix<float>(myImg2.Height * myImg2.Width, 1);
reshaped_vect = tmp.Reshape(1, myImg2.Height * myImg2.Width);
```

**Second usage**

```
mySketch = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(a);
mySketch2 = mySketch.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

Matrix<float> tmp_sketch = new Matrix<float>(mySketch2.Height, mySketch2.Width);
CvInvoke.cvConvert(mySketch2, tmp_sketch);
tmp_sketch = tmp_sketch.Transpose();
Matrix<float> sketch_reshaped_vect = new Matrix<float>(mySketch2.Height * mySketch2.Width, 1);
sketch_reshaped_vect = tmp_sketch.Reshape(1, mySketch2.Height * mySketch2.Width);
```

Thanks for Ur helps in advance.

Answer (score 0):

well it seems that I was mistaking...apparently the "array" element (which System provides) of  an Emgu structure does not give the correct information and one should check the MCvMat data...in my case, the "array" element of my matrix, after reshaping, is of the size 144*151 (which is totally incorrect), but the MCvMat data shows that its Rows is 21744 and its Cols is 1 (which is correct).